# Android imageview matrix operations

Tags: android, matrix

Me used `imageview` to display image.
I set the scale type as `ScaleType.MATRIX`
There is option for `scaling` (`zooming`), `dragging` and all. All this are done by doing matrix manipulations mainly `postTranslate` and `postScale`
My problem now it can be drag such that the image is not in the screen
So how we get how much it is dragged.
**In brief**
I have two matrix (`android.graphics.Matrix`) one the initial stage and the other that i got after drag and zoom. Now from this 2 matrices i want to calculate **how much it moved in x-direction and y-direction?**
What matrix operation i need to do here.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can get float array of matrix's values using getValues function. The 2nd (Matrix.MTRANS_X) and 5th (Matrix.MTRANS_Y) values of matrix are transitions in x and y directions.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html

Comment: This video goes into some good detail on the math behind this stuff: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IiXB6tYtY4w

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the matrix to get the transformed coordiantes. Matrix class has a few methods that will give you tranformed coordinates.

Look at

- mapPoints
- mapVectors
- mapRect

Once you have the points (original and the transformed) you can easily calculate the distance using [euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance).